# django-rest-framework, how to paginate

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

This is my view witch works ok:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import serializers
from gamerauntsia.berriak.serializers import BerriaSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json



class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@csrf_exempt
def app_berria_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        berriak = Berria.objects.all()
        serializer = BerriaSerializer(berriak, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

I want the response paginated by 5 items, so I tried adding this in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

Do I need to change something more to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializers don't paginate by themselves, you have to call the pagination class with the queryset as an argument. The built-in `rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet` will do both the JSON parsing/rendering and pagination by default without you having to do anything.

Why not have a viewset class such as:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
class BerriaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Berria.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BerriaSerializer
```

This will do everything you want I believe.

If you insist on doing it the way you are, however, you can do the following:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
@csrf_exempt
def app_berria_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        berriak = Berria.objects.all()
        paginator = PageNumberPagination()
        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(berriak, request)
        serializer = BerriaSerializer(page, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I´ll go with viewset ... that great! I didn´t know about them :D